# C# Override when there are specific methods involved in a variable / object

Tags: c#, oop, abstract-base-class

I know how to create virtual methods and override them.   Example

BaseClass:

```
var service = GetConnectionKeyString();

protected virtual string GetConnectionKeyString()
{
    return "wpshook";
}
```

SubClass:

```
protected override string GetConnectionKeyString()
{
   return "newthing";
}
```

However, I want to change a message in which it has JObject with method calls and other objects

Currently in the abstract base class method is this code

```
var message = JObject.FromObject(new
        {
            Component = GetComponentName(),
            WorkflowName = workspaceContext.WorkItem.Workflow.TransactionName,
            RecordType = GetRecordType(configuration, workspaceContext),
            RecordId = GetRecordId(configuration, workspaceContext),
            RecordStatus = GetRecordStatus(configuration, workspaceContext),
            ICN = GetICN(configuration, workspaceContext),

        });
```

So I was adding a virtual method to override this message

```
 protected virtual string OverRideNotificationMessage()
 {
    return "";   //open/close principle  -  don't effect the other subclasses
 }
```

So in my subclass, with an override - how would I be able to replace nearly half the code in "var message"  ?

Example

```
    //replace  
    ICN = GetICN(configuration, workspaceContext) 
    //with 
    FileName = .....
```

Per the comments...

```
var message = JObject.FromObject(new
        {
            Component = GetComponentName(),
            WorkflowName = workspaceContext.WorkItem.Workflow.TransactionName,
            RecordType = GetRecordType(configuration, workspaceContext),
            RecordId = GetRecordId(configuration, workspaceContext),
            RecordStatus = GetRecordStatus(configuration, workspaceContext),
            //per comment replace  ICN with FileName, and possibly replace other lines
            FileName = GetFileName(configuration, workspaceContext),

        });
```

UPDATE with specific example:

Base class :

```
 public abstract class BaseStatusNotification<TContext> : IWorkflowRule<TContext> where TContext : IWorkflowContext
{
    public StepResult Process(IWorkflowClient workflowClient, ITransactionStep configuration, TContext workspaceContext)
    {

        var message = JObject.FromObject(new
        {
            Component = GetComponentName(),
            WorkflowName = workspaceContext.WorkItem.Workflow.TransactionName,
            RecordType = GetRecordType(configuration, workspaceContext),
            RecordId = GetRecordId(configuration, workspaceContext),
            RecordStatus = GetRecordStatus(configuration, workspaceContext),
            ICN = GetICN(configuration, workspaceContext),

        });

        // this most likely should not be here, but only in a subclass
        // wondering if I should have if statement is override is not null?
        OverRideNotificationMessage(configuration, workspaceContext, message);

        var serviceBusClient = QueueManagerFactory.GetQueueSender(workspaceContext.InstanceId,
                                                                    workspaceContext.WorkItem.Workflow.Component,
                                                                    GetConnectionKeyString(), null);

        if (serviceBusClient == null)
        {
            return StepResult.Error;
        }

        serviceBusClient.Enqueue(TimeSpan.Zero, message);

        return StepResult.Success;

    }
    protected virtual string GetConnectionKeyString()
    {
        return "wpshook";
    }

    protected virtual string OverRideNotificationMessage(ITransactionStep configuration, TContext workspaceContext, JObject message)
    {
        return "";
    }
```

Then a typical subclass:

```
public class SendClaimStatusNotification : BaseStatusNotification<IBizClaimWorkflowContext>
{

    protected override string GetICN(ITransactionStep configuration, IBizClaimWorkflowContext workspaceContext)
    {
        var claimHeader = workspaceContext.GetClaimHeader();
        return claimHeader.AdditionalClaimId;
    }

    protected override string GetRecordStatus(ITransactionStep configuration, IBizClaimWorkflowContext workspaceContext)
    {
        var claimHeader = workspaceContext.GetClaimHeader();
        return claimHeader.StatusCode;
    }

    protected override string GetRecordId(ITransactionStep configuration, IBizClaimWorkflowContext workspaceContext)
    {
        var claimHeader = workspaceContext.GetClaimHeader();
        return claimHeader.ClaimId;

    }

    protected override string GetRecordType(ITransactionStep configuration, IBizClaimWorkflowContext workspaceContext)
    {
        return "Claim";
    }

    protected override string GetComponentName()
    {
        return FrameworkConstants.Components.VidaClaim;           
    }
    protected override string GetConnectionKeyString()
    {
        return "wpshook";
    }
}
```

NOW, I am wanting to have an override to swap out the var message....

It isn't clear to me how I can replace the several of those anonymous types and methods in the JObject that produces json ..  I was playing with a new subclass and creating this

```
protected override string OverRideNotificationMessage(ITransactionStep configuration, ITEDTransactionWorkflowContext workspaceContext, JObject message)
    {
        var messageq = JObject.FromObject(new
        {
            Component = GetComponentName(),
            WorkflowName = workspaceContext.WorkItem.Workflow.TransactionName,
            RecordType = GetRecordType(configuration, workspaceContext),
            RecordId = GetRecordId(configuration, workspaceContext),
            RecordStatus = GetRecordStatus(configuration, workspaceContext),
            //ICN = GetICN(configuration, workspaceContext),
            FileName = "something else"

        });

        return base.OverRideNotificationMessage(configuration, workspaceContext, message);
    }
```

Comment: Your final question is completely disconnected from the rest of explanation. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @trailmax  Sorry -   ICN = GetICN is inside the var message ... and for example that json structure I want to replace the ICN with  FileName ...along with other fields.    I'm just lost on how to replace  var message - JObject  etc... with passing in an override

Comment: I'm sorry, this is clear as mud. Perhaps if you show us (edit your question) both code examples of original and then second, we'll be able to suggest a way to unify your code.

Comment: @trailmax  Ok  I updated the question   ,   I am not sure if i could end up with a if statement and pass in the new message body ...  ?

Comment: It is not clear how `OverRideNotificationMessage` and `message` and `GetFileName` are related. `abstract base class method is this code` which method ? `I was adding a virtual method to override this message` where? It would be helpful to share entire baseclass and derived class code only relevant to this question. Also share some more details around what's expected behavior and what you are actually getting.

Comment: @trailmax   updated with more complete code of base class and subclasses

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya    OK -  updated  Hopefully this now makes sense.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Really unsure as to what you're asking here so this is a best guess - have you considered returning `message` from another method which you override with your custom logic? You can not break the flow of code mid-way through a function just to change state - not without that state coming from a virtual or abstract method which is implemented on the derived type.

Comment: @ColinM  -  have you considered looking at the pasted base class and subclass and providing an answer with something instead of adding to the comments?

Comment: Somehow I think you should separate the sending of the message and the formatting in different classes. Maybe create a IMessageFormatter interface and different implementations, which generate different JSON-Messages. And the MessageSender could use the IMessageFormatter...

Comment: I can't answer a question which I find makes little sense, but I see an answer has been given which uses the approach I'd thought may have worked - so no issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly your requirement,  what you are looking for is changing the structure of the generated json object, depending on the subclass that is creating the json message.

Does this help?

```
// this is defined in a superclass
public virtual JObject NewMessage() {
   var message = JObject.FromObject(new
        {
            Component = GetComponentName(),
            WorkflowName = workspaceContext.WorkItem.Workflow.TransactionName,
            RecordType = GetRecordType(configuration, workspaceContext),
            RecordId = GetRecordId(configuration, workspaceContext),
            RecordStatus = GetRecordStatus(configuration, workspaceContext),
            ICN = GetICN(configuration, workspaceContext),

        });
   return message;
}

public StepResult Process(IWorkflowClient workflowClient, ITransactionStep configuration, TContext workspaceContext)
{
    // instead of hardcoding the message structure, call an overridable function
    // so we may provide a different message structure if needed
    var message = NewMessage();
    ...
}
```

Then a subclass could override NewMesage() and provide a different structrure

```
public override JObject NewMessage() {
   var message = JObject.FromObject(new
     {
            Component = GetComponentName(),
            WorkflowName = workspaceContext.WorkItem.Workflow.TransactionName,
            RecordType = GetRecordType(configuration, workspaceContext),
            RecordId = GetRecordId(configuration, workspaceContext),
            RecordStatus = GetRecordStatus(configuration, workspaceContext),
            FileName = "something else"  // FileName instead of ICN

     });
   return message;
}
```

Here you have a lot of flexibility, since you can override any of the `Get...` methods if you want to tailor how a specific member gets its value, or you can override the `NewMessage()` method and provide a whole different message structure if that is the requirement